# I want to create a custom computer board with USB and Ethernet feature that runs linux.

Tags: arm, microprocessor

I want to make a computer board which only has USB and Ethernet.
And the board should run linux.
Actually I want to download some data from internet and save it on USB device.
I am a programmer I can handle the programming part but I do not know how to get this hardware made at very low cost.
How can I design that the cost is minimum.
Please help me!!!

Comment: whats wrong with buying something ots?

Comment: This is a disgustingly huge hardware project. Just get a beagleboard/beaglebone/raspberry pi and do it that way.

Comment: The minimum cost to buy one of these things is a few tens of dollars. The cost to *build* is months of work and several hundred dollars for the first unit.

Comment: Usb and Ethernet only? Look at Linux based routers and network attached storage devices. The pogo plug or dock star devices are popular. Headless usb stick computers too.

Comment: This can be bought for less than $10 in single quantities -> http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/unbranded/a5-v11  . It has Ethernet, USB, WiFi, and pre-built Linux image.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get something for very low cost, building a board yourself that runs Linux is a *very* bad idea.

First of all, you will need to either design the circuit or gt something open source.  Assuming the later, you still need to enter a schematic and do the board layout.  For that you need a layout and routing program like Eagle.  Okay, they have a hobbyist version of which is $169 -- very cheap for this sort of thing.  (You can't use their freeware version because you need more than two layers.)

So far so good, except that you will have spent a month or more of time doing that, since you have no experience with board layout.  Now you will need to get a board made.  But generally you can't get just one board, usually a minimum of four.  Figure $250 for this, since you've got four layers you can't get the discounted price.

Now you need to buy parts.  $100 will probably do.  Assembly?  Better do it yourself, assembly houses will charge you $500 for just one board.  You'll need to build an oven to do the SMD soldering, there's lots of info on the web on making one.  But good luck.  Parts for that and a good temperature-controlled soldering iron will run another $150.

So we're up to $669 and a few to several months of work. Oh, you need to port a distro of Linux to your board?  There goes another month or more.

Wouldn't it be easier to buy a [Raspberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-2-model-b/) for $35?

Comment: and imagine the weeks of firmware/hardware debugging hell and the horribly uncertainty and obvious inexperience and many more strange questions to EE.SE lol